# Assigning values to Struct of Vectors in Bluespec SV

Tags: hdl, bluespec

```
typedef struct {
    Vector#(4, INDEX)             index;
    Vector#(2, TAG1)     comp_tag1_table;
    Vector#(2, TAG2)     comp_tag2_table;
   } Prediction_Packet deriving(Bits, Eq, FShow);
```

```
Prediction_Packet pred_pkt <- mkReg(unpack(0));
```

In the above BSV code, I need to assign values to `comp_tag1_table` (having 2 entries of TAG1 data type) and `comp_tag2_table` (having 2 entries of TAG2 data type).

I have tried using...something like...
`pred_pkt.comp_tag1_table[ti] <= 8'b101` where ti can be 0 or 1 but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. It can't be an array I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`pred_pkt.comp_tag1_table[ti] = 8'b0101;` can be used if its a variable. Ofcourse its a variable.

`<=` is used in the case of assigning values to registers.

Answer (score 0):

BSV does not support updating a field or element of a register. If pred_pkt is a register, then you could do:

```
let new_pred_pkt = pred_pkt;
new_pred_pkt.comp_tag1_table[ti] = 8'b101;
pred_pkg <= new_pred_pkt;
```